# Blazor Server No Hot Reload

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, hot-reload

I have a Blazor Server app that initially developed for dotnet 5. I'm using VS 2022 Pro.

I'd like to make use of hot reload so I've done the following:

```
csproj file: <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
```

This doesn't give me hot reload functionality for this project. If I create a new Blazor Server project they hot-reload works but I can't see what's different in config?

Below is the content of launchSettings.json from my project:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:63697",
      "sslPort": 44396
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "SmsRouter.Website": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7040;http://localhost:5041",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've compared this to the same file from the sample App for which hot reload does work:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:9743",
      "sslPort": 44313
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "BlazorApp1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7040;http://localhost:5041",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can't spot the difference?

Comment: Take a closer look / compare with `launchSettings.json` in the properties folder.